# Java web app where to put settings

Tags: java, xml, maven, config

I have a multi-module Maven Java project in `NetBeans`.

Using `Context env = (Context)new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env");` I can get settings from the web.xml file in the web app module code.

However, I can't work out how to get the settings in the other modules from the `web.xml` file.

One of the other modules deals with email tasks such as sending welcome emails to new users.

What I'd like to do is get the settings for the email server from the web.xml file into the email module. Currently, I have hard coded the settings in the code.

Then on the server the settings are easy to change if necessary.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways how to do that. You can put settings in properties files, or you can put them to pom.xml or into database.

It depends on when you want to change it. If you want to change it in compile time, choose pom.xml. if you want to change it during stating up application, put them into properties files. And if you want to change them while app is up, save them into database (can be file).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, mate. I'll look into all of them. Cheers.